# Thevenin Voltage of the circuit

Tags: thevenin

Suppose I have the following circuit, How do I compute Vth using the node voltages?[image]

I simulated a circuit similar to this one with values.

I got:

Vnode1 = 5.93 kV

Vnode2 = 12.4 kV

Vnode3 = 5.64 kV

With Isc = 1.85 A and Rth = 1293.53 ohms, I got Vth = 2393.65 V.

Playing with the node voltages' values does not seem to be getting a 2393.65 V.

Sorry I used the wrong meter for measuring Rth it should be 3661.97 ohms, I know now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$V_{th}=V_{\text{node3}} - V_{\text{node2}}$$